# Has_and_belongs_to same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, join

I have and User model that will need to 'own' itself. Thats because the only way to a user connect with another is if they have this 'bound'.

So... I created a 'join model':

```
class CreateUserConnections < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :user_connections, id: false do |t|
      t.string :token
      t.integer :user_a_id, :null => false
      t.integer :user_b_id, :null => false

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :user_connections, :token, unique: true
    add_index :user_connections, [:user_a_id, :user_b_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

and

```
class UserConnection < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :user_a, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :user_b, :class_name => 'User'

  before_create :generate_token

  protected

  def generate_token
    self.token = loop do
      random_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
      break random_token unless UserConnection.exists?(token: random_token)
    end
  end
end
```

and then created the relation on my user model:

```
#unlocked users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users,
                          :join_table => "user_connections",
                          :foreign_key => "user_a_id",
                          :association_foreign_key => "user_b_id"
```

The problem is that when I create a relation with a user like:

```
User.find(1).users << User.find(2)
```

It creates the own relation from User 1 to User 2, but I tought that with the many_to_many relation the ownership relation from user 2 to 1 would be automatic.

What I'm missing here?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should create the reverse realationship by myself.